# Tools for creating and exporting a LOT of icons?

Tags: icon, export, automation, batch-processing

I have to create and a large number of icons (multiple sizes and colors of a couple hundred icons). Sizes can range pretty drastically (largest at 256x256px, smallest at 14x14px) so I also have to be able to be able to have really nice sharp vector-like shapes at the larger sizes and pixel-perfect icons at the smallest sizes.

I'm looking for an process or software that is really good at handling such high volume. Something that exports in multiple sizes would be excellent. Another thing that saves a lot of time is being able to specify a specific naming convention or naming slices in advance so that they export and are automatically the right file name when I export them.

If there is anything that will handle this process or a good chunk of it, please let me know!

Comment: Fireworks can do this. But, that said, it'd help to know what the end-environment will be. For the web, you often want to keep all of your icons as one file--or possibly as a font.

Comment: "Pixel-perfect at the smallest size" cannot be automated. Computers are the *worst* in deciding which pixels are significant.

Comment: These are needed for a number of applications (software, web, mobile). I don't think a font will work for my purposes. Is there anything other than Fireworks (since they no longer support that) that you know of? I'm also aware that software will not parse pixel-perfect icons for me...but if there is a software that can support both at least that would be helpful.

Comment: If you're using Illustrator, I strongly recommend the MultiExporter script, more info at [What is the best practice for laying out and exporting custom icons from AI?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/37722/what-is-the-best-practice-for-laying-out-and-exporting-custom-icons-from-ai/37729#37729) If you're not, I'd recommend using Illustrator with the MultiExporter script...

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, if the environment you are going to be using the icons is software, web, and mobile, there is absolutely no reason to not use **Sprite Images** to solve this.

Sprite Images allow you to save in size and, most importantly, in requests to the server. You could also have a responsive approach, where you would have all your icons in a different file per resolution.

Chris Coyier talks about the benefits of CSS Sprites in [this article](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/) and I think it's quite self explanatory.

Comment: I'm more looking for a software that will help me automate image exports and file naming, whether it is sprites or individual icons. I have cases that require both. Simply making a sprite does not solve the problem I am asking. I are talking about creating and exporting literally thousands of images in a lot of sizes, formats, etc...

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Sketch](http://bohemiancoding.com/sketch/). It does not have pixel editing per se, but it will give you a high degree of control over how your nodes are placed and lets you preview in pixels. And it has an unbeatable export process. You can export at 2x,3x, etc with one click.