# Why won't "Multiexporter" export any artboards? ("Will export 0 of X artboards")

Tags: adobe-illustrator, export, artboard

I use the **Multiexporter script** ([blog article explanation](http://www.ericson.net/content/2011/06/export-illustrator-layers-andor-artboards-as-pngs-and-pdfs/), [github link](https://gist.github.com/TomByrne/7816376)) for bulk exports of PNGs or PDFs from many artboards. It usually works fine, but sometimes it refuses to co-operate, with a message like:

> Will export 0 of 10 artboards

...even though there are plenty of artboards with content on them. There's no clue as to what the problem is, except a line about "currently visible layers" - but they do all have currently visible layers. Adding prefixes, suffixes and output directories make no difference.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out Multiexporter **ignores artboards that haven't been named**. Enter a name for each artboard, and they'll be included (that name will also be used for the filename).

For example here, it's recognising each artboard that doesn't have the default name.

[image]

If you create an artboard by alt-dragging an existing artboard, the copy will appear if the original had a name and won't if it didn't:

[image]

Unfortunately I don't know of any quick way to name hundreds of artboards.